# Injectivity of the universal map to the tensor product

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Given real vector spaces $X$ and $Y$, there's a canonical bilinear map $$X,Y \rightarrow X \otimes Y$$ given by $x,y \mapsto x \otimes y$. It seems likely that if $x \in X$ is non-zero, then the map $y \mapsto x \otimes y$ is injective.

> **Question.** Is this true, and if so, how might one go about proving it from the universal property?

Comment: Do you mean to say "if $x$ is non-zero"?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, yes, thank you. It was late :)

Answer (score 3):

I assume you mean to ask something equivalent to

> If $x \in X$ is non-zero, show that the map $y \mapsto x \otimes y$ is injective.

Fix $x_0 \in X$.  Of course, the map $y \mapsto x \otimes y$ is linear, so it suffices to show that this map has a trivial kernel.  Fix any $y_0 \in Y$.  If we assume the axiom of choice, then there certainly exist linear maps $f:X \to \Bbb R$ and $g: Y \to \Bbb R$ such that $f(x_0) = 1$ and $g(y_0) = 1$.  We may define the bilinear map $\Phi:X \times Y \to \Bbb R$ by
$$
\Phi(x,y) = f(x) g(y)
$$
Clearly, $\Phi(x_0,y_0) \neq 0$.  By the universal property, we see that there is an induced linear map $\tilde \Phi : X \otimes Y \to \Bbb R$ satisfying $\tilde \Phi(x_0 \otimes y_0) \neq 0$. It follows that $x_0 \otimes y_0 \neq x_0 \otimes 0$.